# How do I combine those two SPF record?

Tags: spf

I have two of them but I am not sure exactly format to combine them? Thank you for helping!

v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all

v=spf1 a:outbound5.bullhorn.com a:outbound3.bullhorn.com a:outbound2.bullhorn.com a:o1.email.bullhorn.com ~all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combined record should look like this:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com a:outbound5.bullhorn.com a:outbound3.bullhorn.com a:outbound2.bullhorn.com a:o1.email.bullhorn.com -all
```

You will have to decide between the `-all` and `~all` since you can only have one of them. Which one to choose depends a little on how you want to handle unmatched mails (fail or softfail). If you are sure that only the listed servers will be sending mails for your domain, you should use `-all` unless you use DMARC which may prefer `~all` (the blocking will be handled by DMARC)

If most of your outgoing mails are sent through bullhorn, you may want to move the include part to the end of the list (right before the all). This will reduce the number of DNS lookups on the receiving servers, since the evaluation will stop when a match is found.

Comment: Good answer. With a pattern of naming like that, it wouldn't surprise me if bullhorn have an SPF record you can include.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! I was having trouble to combine it and godaddy is our domain host and they can't do it for us as we have to do it our own.  What happen we have SPF from bullhorn, but we have the outlook one too. so two of the TXT is making it have problems. they was told if you combine it and it will be good. Thank you again for the help